# What are the best especial effects programs for Ubuntu ? And how can I install it?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

I need a program to do special effect for a school project so I need a program like adobe after effects, but for Ubuntu.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org):

Features:

- Photorealistic Rendering
- Fast Modeling
- Realistic Materials
- Fast Rigging
- Animation toolset
- Sculpting
- Fast UV Unwrapping
- And much more. Check them [here](https://www.blender.org/features/)

Install latest version from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

[image]

---

**[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/):**

> Avidemux is a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering
>   and encoding tasks. It supports many file types, including AVI, DVD
>   compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs. Tasks
>   can be automated using projects, job queue and powerful scripting
>   capabilities.

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install avidemux
```

[image]

---

[**Cinelerra**](http://cinelerra.org/)

Installation :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

---

[**Kdenlive**](https://kdenlive.org/)

> Kdenlive is an intuitive and powerful multi-track video editor,
>   including most recent video technologies.

Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

[image]

---

- [Kino](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/kino/)
- [LiVES](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/lives/)

[**Lumiera**](http://lumiera.org/)

> Lumiera is a Free/Open Source Non-Linear Video Editing (NLE)
>   application project for GNU/Linux
>
> It was born as a rewrite of the CinelerraCV codebase, but developed
>   later into an independent project with its own name. The application
>   is still in an pre-alpha state and not usable for normal work.

[Installation from source](http://www.g-raffa.eu/Cinelerra/LumieraCompilation.html)

[apt-get installation](http://lumiera.org/debian/)

[image]

- OpenShot Video Editor
- Pitivi
- Shotcut
- VideoLan Movie Creator (VLMC)

Comment: But with Avidemux can I make special effects like fire or lasers ?

Comment: look at Blender. It's a great app

Comment: And with all this programs can I make special effects like explosions or lasers ?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/)

The full package list is documented here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuStudio/PackageList

Or you can just install the packages with apt-get in your Ubuntu installation. 
You can find all packages by using

```
 apt-cache search ubuntustudio
```

The packages are called e.g. ubuntustudio-audio, ubuntustudio-video, ubuntustudio-font-meta and many more. Please note that installing the font package will give you a huge bulk of really awesome fonts where you will get lost once you start digging.